# Could not load file or assembly when Integrating Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

I am trying to integrate Azure Keyvault to a web API. Here's the code from a [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
  var builtConfig = config.Build();
                    using (var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
                    {
                        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                        var certs = store.Certificates
                            .Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                builtConfig["AzureKeyVault:CertThumbprint"], false);

                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                            $"https://{builtConfig["AzureKeyVault:Vault"]}.vault.azure.net/",
                            builtConfig["AzureKeyVault:ClientId"],
                            certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Single());

                        store.Close();
                    }
```

However, I got an error saying:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform,
>   Version=3.14.2.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault

Here's the StackTrace:

> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine&
>   stateMachine)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationExtensions.GetTokenFromClientCertificate(String
>   authority, String resource, String clientId, X509Certificate2
>   certificate)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__9.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__10.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.d__66.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.d__49.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.d__5.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1
>   providers)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException&
>   hostingStartupErrors)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()

Does anyone know what's the reason?

Comment: Try to upgrade the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` to the latest version.

Comment: yea i did but its still the same error @JoyWang

Comment: This same block of code worked for me before but I"m now getting the exact same error.

Comment: In my specific case my issue arises if I add serilog mssql sinks. When I remove that nuget reference the key vault loading works again. So it's possible you also have an issue being caused by other package references.